# owl carousel activator div class name

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        loop: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 5
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The above code is working fine. But when I change the class named `owl-carousel`, it is not working. My question is why it's not working with any other class. Is it required to keep the class name `owl-carousel`.

Thanks.

Comment: You must also need to change the class name of the element that currently has a `owl-carousel` class to the same class you defined in `$('.whatever-class').owlCarousel({`

Comment: Only `owl-carousel` class name is working. Any other class name not working.

Answer (score 3):

You should add `owl-carousel` class to the element in all cases,
ex:

```
<div class="your-own-class owl-carousel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the basic demo of the carousel make confusing, it should be.

```
<div class="carousel-one owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
 
</div>
```

and js

```
$('.carousel-one').owlCarousel({ 
    items: 3,
    loop: true, 
    dots: true, 
});
```